# CSS Accordion: hyperlink (a) not inheriting style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get [this](https://codepen.io/dandiws/pen/qqyeed) to work:

```css
body {
  background-color: #c15236;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding: 2em 6em;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}


/*--------Accordion-------*/

.acc-kontainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.acc-kontainer .acc-body {
  width: 98%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  ;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.acc-kontainer label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100;
}

.acc-kontainer input {
  display: none;
}

.acc-kontainer label:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f067';
  font-weight: bolder;
  float: right;
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked+label {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked+label:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f00d';
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked~.acc-body {
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Pure HTML+CSS Accordion (Without Javascript)</h1>
  <div class="acc-kontainer">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc1" checked>
      <label for="acc1"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> My name?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        Hi, You can call me Dandi.<br><br>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc2">
      <label for="acc2"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> What am I interesting for?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        All the thing about Technology! Informatic technology especially.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc3">
      <label for="acc3"><i class="fa fa-music"></i> What is my hobby?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        i love music <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>, watching movie <i class="fa fa-film"></i>, Designing maybe <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, when I add a hyperlink to the "answer" they fall outside the expanded box.
The `<a>` element is inside the `<div>` but it still falls outside the div element for some reason.

If I add a style for the `<a>` element and let it inherit everything, it kind of works.
It inherits the style, but it still falls outside of the div element which ruins it all.

Any idea how to fix this?

I need it to be with CSS only.

Comment: you need overflow:hidden on your div element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden;` to the "closed" accordion styles (`.acc-kontainer .acc-body`). See below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #c15236;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  padding: 2em 6em;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}


/*--------Accordion-------*/

.acc-kontainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.acc-kontainer .acc-body {
  width: 98%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  ;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.acc-kontainer label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100;
}

.acc-kontainer input {
  display: none;
}

.acc-kontainer label:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f067';
  font-weight: bolder;
  float: right;
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked+label {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked+label:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f00d';
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.acc-kontainer input:checked~.acc-body {
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Pure HTML+CSS Accordion (Without Javascript)</h1>
  <div class="acc-kontainer">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc1" checked>
      <label for="acc1"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> My name?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        Hi, You can call me Dandi.<br><br>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc2">
      <label for="acc2"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> What am I interesting for?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        All the thing about Technology! Informatic technology especially.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="acc" id="acc3">
      <label for="acc3"><i class="fa fa-music"></i> What is my hobby?</label>
      <div class="acc-body">
        i love music <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>, watching movie <i class="fa fa-film"></i>, Designing maybe <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```